# Moisture damage in exterior wall - trying to figure out cause/remedy

Tags: water, moisture, water-damage

So we moved a mattress that was covered in plastic sheeting and had been there since the summer leaning against the wall and discovered this. The plastic sheeting had water on it as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

A couple things to know -

there has been a small levoit humidifier running in the room, but the humidity has been in the 50-60% range at an average temp of 18-19 degrees celsius (64-66 F), as well as a radiant space heater. neither of these are located close to the water damage. the space is heated via forced air, but gets quite cold and dry in the winter.

the wall is an exterior wall and doesn't have much insulation - it has gotten quite cold here

1970s construction - there is no vapour barrier in the wall, just paper backed fibreglass. we are renoing in May and will be reframing and insulating all exterior walls and adding a vapour barrier.

the drywall doesn't seem super soft on preliminary examination

I am thinking that either

there is a means of ingress in the brick/mortar wall

there is a means of ingress from the seam of the window (installed 1.5 years ago). the damage seems pretty far from the window though.

it is a result of condensation stuck there from the "vapour barrier" of the mattress leaning against the wall and exacerbated by the cold temperatures/barely insulated wall and humidifier

Should I tear out the drywall, or wait and see, or is there something I'm not thinking of?

Thanks everyone. Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that either water has condensed behind the plastic sheet or someone tipped some some accidentally.

It looks like it is just the paper that is bulging.  You can prove it by pressing it.  If its feel like paper, then there is only superficial damage.

Just sand, prime and paint should work.

Comment: That's not just superficial damage - the paper is a major component of the drywall. To repair, the loose paper needs to be removed and a skim coat needs to be applied, however it would better to replace with new drywall if the damaged area is too big